# Custom filter in ng-repeat ran 1200 instead of 100?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

I have a an array that holds 100 objects. And with `ng-repeat` I create table fill it with data. And I also have a filter function that is filtering my table. Initially (on-load) filter values are set so that every row from 100 will pass, but later user can change filter values and with two-way binding, my table updates automatically. But here is the big problem that I do not know how to solve. I have added counter to my filter function and instead of running 100 times on-load it ran 1200 times on-load and 800 times each time user change filter values. Here is the demo of my array (only 10 object and not real data):

```
$scope.carList = [{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchbak"},{"name":"car", "review":"250", "rating":  "4.5", "fiveStarPercent": "70%", "recommended": "90%", "carLink":"http://someurl.com", "price": "$1000-$2000", "minPrice": "1000", "maxPrice":"2000", "type": "hatchback"}];
```

Here is my controller and my filter function:

```
carApp.controller("TableBodyCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){

$scope.selectAll = {"selected":true};
$scope.filterValues = {revNum:30,minNum:0,maxNum:0,currentCarType:null};
$scope.modelRow = { activeRow: '' };
$scope.carTypeObj = [];
$scope.showDetails = false;
$scope.carTypeArray = [];
$scope.activeTypeBox = false;

$scope.tableFilter = function(line) {
    smartCounter++
    console.log(smartCounter);

    var revNum = (($scope.filterValues.revNum===null) ? 0 : $scope.filterValues.revNum);
    var minNum = (($scope.filterValues.minNum===null) ? 0 : $scope.filterValues.minNum);
    var maxNum = (($scope.filterValues.maxNum===null) ? 0 : $scope.filterValues.maxNum);

    var typeBool = false;
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.carTypeObj.length;i++){
        if ($scope.carTypeObj[i]["selected"] && $scope.carTypeObj[i]["type"]===line["type"]){
            if ($scope.selectAll["selected"] === true){
                $scope.selectAll["selected"] = false;
            }
            typeBool = true;
        }
    }

    if ($scope.selectAll["selected"] === true){
        typeBool = true;
    }

    var r = line["review"] >= revNum;
    var minP = line["maxPrice"] >= minNum && line["maxPrice"]!="";
    if(maxNum!=0){
        var maxP = line["minPrice"] <= maxNum && line["minPrice"]!="";
    }else{
        var maxP = true;
    }
    $scope.progressBar += 1

    return(r && maxP && minP && typeBool && ((line["type"] == $scope.filterValues.currentCarType) || ($scope.filterValues.currentCarType == null)));

}
}]);
```

And here is my html:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Car Model</th>
      <th>Reviews</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>5 Star Percentage</th>
      <th>Recommended</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter">
      <td>{{car.name}}</td>
      <td>{{car.review}}</td>
      <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
      <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
      <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
      <td>{{car.price}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I fix this issue:

*Angular version: v1.2.25*

UPDATE:

I am using `ng-repeat-start` because each car object has another object that holds car reviews by year of car registration and I want to show this table when user click on the row:

```
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="modelRow.activeRow==car.name && showDetails && car.allReviews.length!=0" class="hidden-table">
    <td colspan="6">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Reviews</th>
                    <th>Rating <span class="fiveStar">/5</span></th>
                    <th>Recommended</th>
                    <th>Reliability Rating <span class="fiveStar">/5</span></th>
                    <th>Performance Rating <span class="fiveStar">/5</span></th>
                    <th>Running Costs Rating <span class="fiveStar">/5</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="rev in car.allReviews">
            ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decrease the number of times your filter function is called by leveraging [$filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/service/$filter).  After injecting $filter into your controller and initializing $scope.carList, insert this line:

```
$scope.filteredCarList = $filter('filter')($scope.carList, $scope.tableFilter);
```

Then in your view, change the ng-repeat to:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="car in filteredCarList">
  <td>{{car.name}}</td>
  <td>{{car.review}}</td>
  <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
  <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
  <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
  <td>{{car.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: excellent. I prefer to separate complex filter logic from html too.

Answer (score 0):

Filter Functions Are Invoked Many, Many Times

Whenever you write a filter, bear in mind that this may get called many, many times. Digest loops can run sequentially several times even in simple AngularJS partials. It is easy to create a filter that can get called fifty times for a table of ten rows every time that view is rendered, not just the first time.

Not so long ago I ran into a filter - more a horrible hack, really - that was doing something like this:

```
someModule.filter('someFilter', function () {
  return function (id) {
    return jQuery('#' + id).children('span').text();
  };
});
```

As you can imagine, this was definitely slowing down the view. It's probably best not to ask what the author was thinking at the time; I didn't, I just replaced it and its role in the partial with code that worked from the underlying data rather than trying to join together loose ends after the fact.

Here are two rules for filters: firstly, if the same effect can be simply achieved by decorating the underlying data, such as by adding a "formattedValue" property, then do it that way. It will always be faster because it only happens once, not multiple times per digest cycle. Secondly, when you do have good reasons to write a filter make sure that it is blindingly fast.

In general, aim to replace this:

```
<span>{{value | formatForDisplay}}</span>
```

With this:

```
<span>{{formattedValue}}</span>
```

[Source](https://www.exratione.com/2013/12/considering-speed-and-slowness-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score -1):

Use just ng-repeat not ng-repeat-start.

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in carList | filter:tableFilter">
  <td>{{car.name}}</td>
  <td>{{car.review}}</td>
  <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
  <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
  <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
  <td>{{car.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: and also it didn't help it still runs 1200 times instead of 100.